# How to list bluetooth devices near me using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, bluetooth, netsh

How to list all Bluetooth devices paired or currently near me and particullary MAC adress ? I want the equivalent of the command :

```
netsh wlan show network mode=bssid
```

I am able to list all Bluetooth devices and characteristics but not MAC adress with the command :

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq "Bluetooth"}
foreach ($device in $devices) { echo $device.InstanceId }
```

Note it is not a problem if I need to manually shrink results and if the list is not in a perfect layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PowerShell command :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DeviceAssociationService\State\Store\ | Select-String -Pattern Bluetooth
```

will print devices already paired :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DeviceAssociationService\State\Store\Bluetooth#BluetoothXX:XX:XX:XX:XX:b2-YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DeviceAssociationService\State\Store\Bluetooth#BluetoothXX:XX:XX:XX:XX:b2-ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DeviceAssociationService\State\Store\BluetoothLE#BluetoothLEXX:XX:XX:XX:XX:b2-WW:WW:WW:WW:WW:WW
```

The `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` values is your Bluetooth MAC adress.

Comment: It needs administrative rights in order to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use registry subkeys from `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`:

```
$devices = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices
foreach($device in $devices) {
    $address=$device.pschildname.ToUpper()
    $name=$device.GetValue("Name")
    if($name -ne $null) {
        $printableName = ($name -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
        echo "Address: $address, Name: $printableName"
    }
}
```